# Can I use YUI Compressor or other tool to combine arbitrary javascript files?

Tags: javascript, dojo

My problem is that I need to combine approximately 200 dojo javascript files.  Dojo uses the AMD define/require module system.  The dojo built-in tools which use Google Closure and Shrinksafe won't work due to a version mismatch (tool is from 1.11.3 source is 1.11.1).

The dojo build includes steps which reference an AST so I'm assuming that you can't just throw any old code at a "combiner".  Presumably global variables and other naming conflicts would be the first problem.

Are the tools generally clever enough to handle any old javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dojo build tools was specifically designed to build dojo application. You won't be able to easily build using YUI or others (like require.js)

You should be able to build from 1.11.3 even if your code is 1.11.1.

Comment: Just a note: For complex application the dojo build configuration could be painful, a good starting point is to use a boilerplate as; https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate